# SQLite delete isn't working

Tags: android, sqlite, delete-row

When I try delete a record in my database it is showing a null pointer exception error. This is my code:

```
ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE[1], KEY_ID + " = " + id, null);
```

Don't worry `id` has a value, I've already checked that!

[image]

```
public class DiaryDB {
// User info
public static final String KEY_NAME = "my_name";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "my_password";
public static final String KEY_QUESTION_ID = "my_question";
public static final String KEY_ANSWER = "my_answer";

// Entry details
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "entry_date";
public static final String KEY_TIME = "entry_time";
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "entry_title";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT = "_entry";
public static final String KEY_RATE = "entry_rating";
public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "entry_image";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDiary";
private static final String[] DATABASE_TABLE = { "My_Details", "My_Entries" };
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

public DiaryDB(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;
}

public DiaryDB open() throws SQLException {
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    ourHelper.close();
}

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE[0] + " (" + KEY_NAME
                + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, " + KEY_PASSWORD
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_QUESTION_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT NOT NULL);");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE[1] + " (" + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_DATE
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_CONTENT
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_RATE + " REAL, " + KEY_IMAGE
                + " BLOB);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE[0]);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE[1]);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}


public void deleteEntry(long id){
    Log.e("Tester", "" + id);
    ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE[1], KEY_ID + " = " + id, null);
}
}
```

Log chat error at:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.releaseAndUnlock(SQLiteStatement.java:290)

Source code available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxB1rWbVlxEJNDVzemdZSWFwR2s/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: show full code...what is DATABASE_TABLE? KEY_ID? id? One of this params is null

Comment: Please add the relevant code. Also add the LogCat in its WRITTEN form, not as a picture.

Comment: Anyway, I can see there's a NullPointerException.

Comment: Your `ourDatabase` is not properly initialized and the internal `mDatabase` member is null. More code needed for further help.

Comment: @Suvitruf,  check out now

Comment: @Der Golem, check out now, can you please tell why?

Comment: Possibly you're calling `deleteEntry()` after `close()`.

Comment: How do you instance `DiaryDB` in the calling class?

Comment: @ Der Golem I've just attached the source code, can please check and tell me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your database could be closed when you are trying to delete the row. Try opening the database before the `delete` and closing it at the end.

Also, as a good advice you should do this if your `ID` is a String:

```
 ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE[1], KEY_ID + "=?" , new String[]{id});
```

Comment: While this is good advice in general, why would it help with OP's specific problem?

Answer (score -1):

```
String where = KEY_ID+ "=?";
String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(id)};
yourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE[1], where, selectionArgs);
```